# Looking for a graphDB

Tags: database, graph

- A Graph DB that can handle around 100k-1M nodes
- We need nodes that can have different types and attributes
- We need edges (associations between nodes) that also can have different types and attributes
- Transactional support (all or nothing commits to DB)
- History of changes to elements (add/remove element, add/remove edge, add/remove/modification of attribute)

  - time-span that during the element existed (could either be supported directly by Graph DB or we created layer on top)

Bonus points:

- Support for some smart graph query language that can be used find nodes

  - To be used for reporting and queries in program
  - SPARQL might be a good if they support. Too complicated query language?
- Support for inheritance between node and edge types (to enable query graph for a more generic element type and then also get the inherited element types)
- Replication and failover to secondary DB, or backup to a central DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) supports everything that you need, but it is not free for commercial projects;

Comment: Im looking for something like Neo4j, but I need more ooptions to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fullfills all your requirements but IntelliDimension has a commercial product that sits on top of Microsoft SQL Server and supports SPARQL. They also provide a SDK for .Net.

http://www.intellidimension.com